# Django signals (Clarification of doubts)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I'm new to Django and watching a series of tutorial videos where we did a project ... In the series they talk about 'signals'.

What is proposed to do is connect some signals at the time of making a user registration on the page

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import *
from .forms import OrderForm, CustomerForm, CreateUserForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .decorators import unauthenticated_user, allowed_users, admin_only

@unauthenticated_user
def registerPage(request):
    form_value = CreateUserForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_value = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form_value.is_valid():
            user = form_value.save()
            username = form_value.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, 'Account was create for {}'.format(username))
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Data is invalid, please try again') 
    context = {'form_key':form_value}
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)
```

**signals.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from .models import Customer

def customer_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwagrs):
    if created:
        group = Group.objects.get(name='customer')
        instance.groups.add(group)
        Customer.objects.create(
                user = instance,
                name = instance.username
            )
        print('Profile created.!')

post_save.connect(customer_profile, sender= User)
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'accounts'
    def ready(self):
        import accounts.signals
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    'accounts',

    'django_filters',
]
```

This are my questions:

1. What is the job of the 'ready()' function in 'apps.py'?
2. The tutorial suggests placing 'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig' in the 'settings.py' file specifically in the 'INSTALLED_APPS' section, is it necessary to place it?
3. Another method suggested by the tutorial is to place default_app_config = 'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig' in the file '**init**.py' .. Which is the most recommended?

The use of these signals seems super practical to develop the functionality of a project in the best way. That is why I want to understand these things as clearly as possible, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Please *don't* use signals: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html